# keyboard language button in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, uikeyboard

Just noticed that in `UITextView` keyboard comes without change language button, unlike in `UITextField`. Why Apple removed this button from `UITextView` keyboard? Is there any way to enable this button? I want people to be able to write notes on any keyboard language added in phone settings.

EDITED: Maybe it will help somebody in the future. Just noticed that I set keyboard type to `UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet` and this option eliminates language button. Closing this question.

P.S. I have 3 languages enabled in test iPhone.

Comment: I can't see any Language related buttons on textview nor textfield...

Comment: This is not true. Both objects present the keyboard with the language button if you have additional keyboards installed. Check your keyboard settings if you use different device.

Comment: you probably have only one language enabled in the simulator or on your device, so you don't see it. Must have more than one language to see the button

Comment: I have 3 languages enabled and I can see language button in UITextField, but not in UITextView. Tested it several times.

Comment: Have you set the `keyboardType` property of the text view? Which value did you set?

Comment: Don't delete the post. It's a bad thing for you.

Comment: Ok. I will leave it active. Hope it can help somebody with same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are completely wrong. there is no difference in UIKeyboard in iOS whatsoever. It only depends on what keyboard types you use.

`UIKeyboardTypeDefault` and `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress` and `UIKeyboardTypeTwitter` all have those.

You set it like this:

```
txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeTwitter;
```

`UIKeyboardTypeDefault` is obviously the default one for any `UITextView` or `UITextField` in iOS.

Comment: Yes, your statement is correct although it didn't helped me to find my mistake. +1 for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone have this problem even when using UIKeyboardTypeDefault on a UITextView, go into the storyboard and make sure "Secure Text Entry" is unchecked. After unchecking this, the keyboard selector will return as well as the quick type keyboard.